# Opening a subdropdown on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, reactjs

Given the below code, i'd like to open dropdown-submenu `Item3` when **clicked**, without closing the parent dropdown. The jquery code in `index.html` is not working, i.e. when i click on `Item3` inside main dropdown, the whole dropdown closes.

Is there any way to make the dropdown-submenu appear on click? This is my code snippet:

```js
$('.dropdown.dropdown-submenu').click(function() {
  $('.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu').css('display', 'block');
  return false;
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li className="dropdown">
    <a
        href="#"
        className="dropdown-toggle"
        data-toggle="dropdown"
        role="button"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded="false"
    >
    <span className="fa fa-files-o navigationGlyphicon"></span>
       MainMenu
    <span className="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul className="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
      <li role="separator" className="divider"></li>
      <li className="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
        <a tabIndex="-1" href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Item3 <span className="caret"></span>
                       </a>
        <ul className="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">SubItem1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SubItem2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? What version?

Comment: @dom_ahdigital, `3.3.7`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using `className` custom attribute for html element but with the default `class` attribute and JQuery you can toggle the submenu in this way:

```js
$('.dropdown.dropdown-submenu').click(function() {
            $('.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu').toggle(); 
            return false;
        });
```

```css
.dropdown-menu{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul className="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
               <a
                  tabIndex="-1"
                  href="#"
                  class="dropdown-toggle"
                  data-toggle="dropdown"
               >Item3 <span class="caret"></span>
               </a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li><a href="#">SubItem1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">SubItem2</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: `className` is react specific. sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the id and href attribute:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#dropdown1" class="link">Menu v</a>
        <ul id="dropdown1" style="display: none;">
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#dropdown2" class="link">Item3 v</a>
               <ul id="dropdown2" style="display: none;">
                   <li><a href="#">SubItem1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">SubItem2</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
</ul>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".link").click(function(){
            var e = $(this).attr("href");
            $(e).toggle();
        })
    })

</script>
```

Example here: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ko6q02xp/)

Comment: i've updated my description (the code), it's closing the main menu when clicked on that subdropdown.

Comment: it works, but it's not what i would like, it basically reloads the same page with sub dropdown in it